# Time interval dropdown array in php

Tags: php

I have a select box with time interval of 15 mins starting from 9 to 8pm which is generated by using below code.

```
function hoursRange($lower = 9, $upper = 20, $step = .25, $format = NULL) {

    if ($format === NULL) {
        $format = 'g:ia'; // 9:30pm
    }
    $times = array();
    foreach(range($lower, $upper, $step) as $increment) {
        $increment = number_format($increment, 2);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode('.', $increment);
        $date = new DateTime($hour . ':' . $minutes * .6);
        $times[(string) $increment] = $date->format($format);
    }
    return $times;
}

$timeArr = hoursRange();
$array = array_values($timeArr);
echo "<select>";
echo "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
foreach($array as $key=>$value){    
$disabled = '';
    echo "<option value=".$key." $disabled>".$value."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

It gives me an select box with options 9:00, 9:15 etc like below

```
Array

    (
        [0] => 9:00am
        [1] => 9:15am
        [2] => 9:30am
        [3] => 9:45am
        [4] => 10:00am
        [5] => 10:15am
        [6] => 10:30am
        [7] => 10:45am
        [8] => 11:00am
        [9] => 11:15am
        [10] => 11:30am
        [11] => 11:45am
        [12] => 12:00pm
        [13] => 12:15pm
        [14] => 12:30pm
        [15] => 12:45pm
        [16] => 1:00pm
        [17] => 1:15pm
        [18] => 1:30pm
        [19] => 1:45pm
        [20] => 2:00pm
        [21] => 2:15pm
        [22] => 2:30pm
        [23] => 2:45pm
        [24] => 3:00pm
        [25] => 3:15pm
        [26] => 3:30pm
        [27] => 3:45pm
        [28] => 4:00pm
        [29] => 4:15pm
        [30] => 4:30pm
        [31] => 4:45pm
        [32] => 5:00pm
        [33] => 5:15pm
        [34] => 5:30pm
        [35] => 5:45pm
        [36] => 6:00pm
        [37] => 6:15pm
        [38] => 6:30pm
        [39] => 6:45pm
        [40] => 7:00pm
        [41] => 7:15pm
        [42] => 7:30pm
        [43] => 7:45pm
        [44] => 8:00pm
    )
```

Note: now my issue is that I have to disabled some options from select box by a condition

current time = 11 am  => than all options earlier to this will be disabled

current time = 2pm => all options earlier to this should be disabled

current time = 3:30pm or 3:48pm then all options before 4 pm should be disabled.

For this I have tried this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
$curretHour =  date("g");

echo "<select>";

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $newArr = explode(':', $value);
    if(($newArr[0] == $currentHour) || $newArr[0] <$currentHour){
        $dis = 'disabled = disabled';
    }else{
        $dis = '';
    }
    echo "<option value=".$key." $dis>".$value."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

but it's not working.

Comment: rather than disabling the times which have already passed, why don't you just set the loop to start at the current time, and then no options before the current time will be available?

Comment: @MatthewKnight yes you are right but this is alreday done and on db stored values are line 1 for 9:15 so i need to disbaled previous time so that keys values remain same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this as a soultion to my problem

--Selects--
  11:00 am
  11:15 am
  11:30 am
  11:45 am
  12:00 pm
  12:15 pm
  12:30 pm
  12:45 pm
  01:00 pm
  01:15 pm
  01:30 pm
  01:45 pm
  02:00 pm
  02:15 pm
  02:30 pm
  02:45 pm
  03:00 pm
  03:15 pm
  03:30 pm
  03:45 pm
  04:00 pm
  04:15 pm
  04:30 pm
  04:45 pm
  05:00 pm

-->

```
<?php 
//date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
//echo date("g");

function hoursRange($lower = 9, $upper = 20, $step = .25, $format = NULL) {

    if ($format === NULL) {
        $format = 'g:ia'; // 9:30pm
    }
    $times = array();
    foreach(range($lower, $upper, $step) as $increment) {
        $increment = number_format($increment, 2);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode('.', $increment);
        $date = new DateTime($hour . ':' . $minutes * .6);
        $times[(string) $increment] = $date->format($format);
    }
    return $times;
}

$currentHour = 9;
$array = $timeArr = hoursRange();
//$array = array_values($timeArr);
echo "<select>";
echo "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
$newArr = explode('.', $key);
    if(($newArr[0] == $currentHour) || $newArr[0] <$currentHour){
        $disabled = 'disabled = disabled';
    }else{
        $disabled = '';
    }   
//$disabled = '';
    echo "<option value=".$i." $disabled>".$value."</option>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
```

///js

```
<select id="test" name="test">
  <option value="1">9:00 am</option>
  <option value="2">10:00 am</option>
  <option value="3">11:00 am</option>
  <option value="4">8:00 pm</option>
</select>

<script>
var selectbox = document.getElementById('test');
//var opt = ['9:00 am', '10:00 am','11:00 am','8:00 pm'];
//var opt = ['00:00'=>'12:00 am','10:00'=>'10:00 am'];

var opt = {}; // no need for an array

opt["900"] = '09:00 am';
opt["1000"] = '10:00 am';
opt["1100"] = '11:00 am';
opt["1200"] = '12:00 pm';
opt["1300"] = '01:00 pm';
opt["1400"] = '02:00 pm';

var curtime = '1400';
var str = curtime.split(':');
//console.log(opt);
selectbox.onchange = function(){
    //alert('here');
 var i=0;
    var list = '';
for (var key in opt) {
    console.log('key');

    if(curtime <= key){
        console.log('if');
        var dis = 'disabled';
        console.log(opt[key]);

    }
    list += '<option '+dis+' value='+i+'>'+opt[key]+'</option>';
    //console.log(key);
    i++;
}
    selectbox.innerHTML = list;
};


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and most readable solution is to use DateTime class. I suggest to create current DateTime first. In the foreach loop you have to create DateTime foreach time and compare with the current one. Possible solution:

```
<?php
function hoursRange($lower = 9, $upper = 20, $step = .25, $format = NULL) {

    if ($format === NULL) {
        $format = 'g:ia'; // 9:30pm
    }
    $times = array();
    foreach(range($lower, $upper, $step) as $increment) {
        $increment = number_format($increment, 2);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode('.', $increment);
        $date = new DateTime($hour . ':' . $minutes * .6);
        $times[(string) $increment] = $date->format($format);
    }
    return $times;
}

$timeArr = hoursRange();
$array = array_values($timeArr);
echo "<select>";
echo "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
$currentDateTime = new \DateTime();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('g:ia', $value);
    $disabled = $dateTime <= $currentDateTime;
    echo "<option value=".$key." $disabled>".$value."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Some comments inside the code might be super helpful :)